# I am trying to add two values of array and store it in the next array

Tags: assembly

The code below suppose to sort array named "array". Then ignore all the zeros it have, add the two lowest digits and store the value into the new array named "parent". The bubble sorting sorts arrays accurately .But its not doing what it suppose to. Can someone please help me with that?

```
    ;huffman seperation

    lea dx,PROMPT_1       ;moving the address of PROMPT_1 message
    call display          ;displays PROMPT_1 message
    lea si,array          ;moving the address of array in source index
    call PRINT_ARRAY      ;prints the whole array on screen
    lea si,array          ;moving the address of array in source index
    call BUBBLE_SORT      ;sorting algorithm to sort an array
    lea dx, PROMPT_2      ;load and display the string PROMPT_2
    call display
    lea si, array         ;set SI=offset address of ARRAY
    lea di, parent        ;loading an address of parent array in DI
    call PRINT_ARRAY      ;call the procedure PRINT_ARRAYT
    mov ax, 0             ;used for moving address of array during addition
    mov cx,512            ;512 times this calculation should be performed
    lea si,array          ;SI= pointer to array

huffloop:
calculation:
    mov bx,[si]           ;loading the address of array in bx
    cmp bx,'0'            ;if array has 0 value then jump to skipstep
    jnz skipstep
condition:
    add si+1,si           ;if condition satisfies then add first two array contents
    mov di,si+1           ;copying the resultant value to parent array too
    mov  [si],0           ;replacing the first lowest value in array to zero
    lea dx,PROMPT_1       ;displaying the result on screen
    call display
    lea si,array
    call PRINT_ARRAY
    lea si,array
    call BUBBLE_SORT      ;doing bubble sorting again for repeating the step
    LEA DX, PROMPT_2      ;load and display the string PROMPT_2
    call display
    lea SI, array         ;set SI=offset address of ARRAY
    call PRINT_ARRAY      ;call the procedure PRINT_ARRAY
    mov ax,0
skipstep:
    add si,2              ;moving to next array address
    jmp calculation       ;jumping to calculation function
    jnz huffloop          ;jumping to huffloop
endofhuff:
```

Comment: Are your conditions and labels correct? You have `jmp calculation` then immediately `jnz huffloop` but those two labels mark the same place, and the second instruction of the two is never executed. Also, the label `condition:` is never jumped to.

Comment: `add si+1,si` and `mov di,si+1` are these even proper instructions?

Comment: I am new in assembly. Maybe I am making a mistake

Comment: It won't even assemble, let alone "not do what it suppose to".

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact your code won't assemble, here is a logical error:

```
calculation:
    mov bx,[si]           ;loading the address of array in bx
    cmp bx,'0'            ;if array has 0 value then jump to skipstep
    jnz skipstep
condition:
    ...
skipstep:
```

the `jnz` is wrong. The branch to `skipstep` will be taken whenever the data is not the ***character*** `'0'`, so only `'0'` will be processed by the loop. The test should be

```
    cmp bx,'0'            ;if array has 0 value then jump to skipstep
    jz skipstep
```